# Error invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

Hola amigos estoy creando un programa en Python y me da ese error.
Aquí les dejo mi codigo para saber si me pueden ayudar,muchas gracias

```
def calculoMediana(list):
  mediana = float(0)
  tamaño = len(list)
  if tamaño %2 ==0:
    mediana = (list[(tamaño // 2)] + list[(tamaño //2)-1])/2
    return mediana
  else:
    mediana = list[(tamaño//2)]
    return mediana

def lista():
  continuar = "SI"
  while continuar.upper() == "SI":
    n = int(input("Ingrese el tamaño del que desea su lista:"))
    cantidad = 0
    list = []
    while cantidad<n:
      valor = int(input("Favor ingrese un valor de la lista:"))
      cantidad = cantidad + 1
      list.append(valor)
    list.sort()
    print (calculoMediana(list))
    continuar = input("Desea continuar (SI/NO)?")

try:
  lista()


except ValueError:
  print("Favor ingrese un numero entero")
  pass
  lista()
```

mi error dice

> valueerror invalid literal for int() with base 10 : 'm'

y luego me da lo mismo pero

> valueerror invalid literal for int() with base 10 : 'p'

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Tanto en esta linea

```
 n = int(input("Ingrese el tamaño del que desea su lista:"))
```

como en esta

```
valor = int(input("Favor ingrese un valor de la lista:"))
```

**estas esperando un valor de tipo numérico** para asignarlo a la variable, ya que esta siendo convertido a entero mediante  `int()`, si introduces un valor no numérico, obtendrás el error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:

---

En realidad tienes un manejo de excepciones pero al realizarlo estas volviendo a llamar la funcion `lista()`, la cual no tiene definido manejo de excepciones, como opción podrías evitar llamar este método y de esta forma terminaría tu programa indicando que debes introducir un numero entero:

```
try:
    lista()

except ValueError:
    print("Favor ingrese un numero entero")
    #pass
    #lista()
```